# Black screen on boot after switch to Nouveau Driver

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 22.04

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04, My Graphics Card is a GTX 1080 Ti.

The file system is an encrypted ZFS.

I have two monitors connected to it. One on its DP port, and the other on its HDMI port.

After I did an NVidia driver update I could no longer launch Blender. The error message said I do not have OpenGL 3.3 support. So I open Updates, and go to the "Additional Drivers" tab, and I see I have the 515 drivers selected. I then change this to the 535 driver, reboot, and still cannot launch Blender.

So I attempt follow advice on this problem, which was to change to the Nouveau driver, and after 15 minutes of usage, change back to the NVidia proprietary 535 driver. Upon reboot right after the change to the Nouveau driver the screens were black. Not even the motherboard's splash screen showed. The computer boots, and I can tell it does by the disk activity light blinking. I can blindly enter my ZFS encryption keys, and I can tell by the familiar disk activity sounds, and blinking light patterns, that the keys are accepted, and the OS is starting up. I tried replugging the video cables to no effect. I know the monitors have power because the "no signal" message appears on them.

I considered the possibility of a failed graphics card. But it is too much coincidence that this problem happened right after the switch to the Noveau driver to make this possibility likely.

My next step will be to try and boot from a rescue flash drive. I would appreciate any suggested alternatives to doing this, and a recommendation on where to download the ISO for one.

Another thing I did was to connect a third monitor to the mother board's video connector. The third monitor is also black, I think because of the GTX 1080 Ti installation. So now I consider removing the GTX 1080 Ti long enough to switch back to the proprietary driver.

Comment: When installing any NVIDIA drivers on the system, even updates or upgrades, make sure to always reboot the system so that the new drivers take effect.  The `nvidia-drivers-535` should be supporting OpenGL 4.6.0.  Just a moment ago I was trying to check my OpenGL version and it kept giving me an error.  As soon as I rebooted the error went away.  I believe there was a recent update to the 535 drivers.  Now when I run my check this is what I get:  `OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 535.129.03`.  I am using a 1060 Ti with Blender and 22.04 just fine.

Comment: Are you able to get to a TTY screen to log in with your username and password by pressing CTRL+ALT+F4 or CTRL+ALT+F5 after everything seems to boot up?

Comment: I am not able to bring up a TTY screen with those keys. The monitor remains black, and gives me the no signal message. I suspect now my GTX 1080 Ti has failed, and when I did have a functioning display my difficulty with Blender was an early manifestation of this.